# How can I split a list item

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to split the first item of a list to two items, for exapmle I am trying to convert:

```
l= [('pzibley/09.03', [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), ('pzibley/09.01', [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

to:

```
l= [([pzibley], [09.03], [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), ([pzibley] , [09.01], [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

I have tried several ways but since I am an amateur I'm not able to do this.

Comment: Post one of the ways that you tried and you will get some help, believe me

Comment: You should clarify the data types you expect for that split, because there are currently two answers that are equally correct, but depending on what the final result actually has to be. i.e. does "09.03" have to be float or str?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[tuple([j] for j in i[0].split('/')) + (i[1],) for i in l]

# [(['pzibley'], ['09.03'], [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]),
#  (['pzibley'], ['09.01'], [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Comment: That doesn't cast `float` on the second piece of the split string

Comment: @James True, it's not sure if OP wants it to be casted though. OP still has `09.03`

Comment: Huh...good point, I didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks.... I wanted it float

Comment: @Hossein If you wanted it float there is another solution that does exactly this already. You should accept the answer that actually solved your problem and specify in your question exactly what it is you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
new_l = []
for tup in l:
    a,b = tup[0].split('/')
    new_l.append(([a], [float(b)], tup[1]))

new_l
# [(['pzibley'], [9.03], [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), (['pzibley'], [9.01], [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Comment: Would the use of `append` be slower than the alternative answers herein that utilize list comprehension?

Comment: In general, yes.  However, unless this is operating over very large amounts of data, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that separates each part in the input `tuple` and reassembles them inside a single tuple:

```
def splitter(tpl):
   a,b = tpl[0].split("/")
   return(([a], [float(b)] , tpl[1]))
```

We can iterate the `splitter` function over list `l`:

```
[splitter(x) for x in l]
```

Running it yields:

```
In [5]: [splitter(x) for x in l]
Out[5]:
[(['pzibley'], [9.03], [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]),
 (['pzibley'], [9.01], [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [('pzibley/09.03', [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), ('pzibley/09.01', [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=(l[i][0].split('/'),l[i][1])

print(l)
```

Since tuples are immutable, you have to reassign to the entire tuple, not just the first element in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner the easiest solution to understand would be an answer along the lines of look through the list and split each item and add them to the list you want in the follow way below:

```
l_new=[]
l= [('pzibley/09.03', [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), ('pzibley/09.01', [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
for i in l:

    temp = i[0].split('/')
    l_new.append(([temp[0]],[temp[1]],i[1]))
print(l_new)
#[(['pzibley'], ['09.03'], [8, 0, 2, 0, 0]), (['pzibley'], ['09.01'], [7, 2, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Comment: That is the wrong output. Take a look again at the output OP is expecting.

Comment: thanks idjaw, missed the tuple bit... but that's ok we have copiers like James to take full credit for correcting peoples work. The brashness is unreal